# Error when I was trying to render a map of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, frontend

I am trying to figure out where my error is in my react js page

I have tried different things like changing it into a state component, return and render statements, etc. But its still giving me

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>   Recipes
>   src/components/Recipes.js:4
>     1 | import React from "react";
>     2 | 
>     3 | const Recipes = (props) => (
>   4 |     
>     5 |      { props.recipes.map((recipe)=> {
>     6 |         return (
>     7 |         
>   View compiled"

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import InputForm from "./components/InputForm";
import Recipes from "./components/Recipes"

const API_KEY= "mykey";

class App extends Component {

  state= {
    recipes: []
  }

  getRecipe  = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const recipeName = e.target.elements.recipename.value;
  const api_call = await fetch(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}&q=${recipeName}&page=2`)

  const data = await api_call.json();
  this.setState({ recipes: data.recipes });
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          React Cookbook
        </header>
        <InputForm getRecipe={this.getRecipe} />
       <Recipes recipes={this.state.recipes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Recipes.js

```
import React from "react";

const Recipes = (props) => (
    <div>
     { props.recipes.map((recipe)=> {
        return (
        <div key={recipe.recipe_id }>
            <img src={recipe.image_url} alt={recipe.title}/>
            <h3>{ recipe.title }</h3>
         </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)

export default Recipes;
```

Comment: Did you double check `data.recipes` returns actual data after your fetch? Maybe in some cases it returns `undefined` which in turn will set the  `recipes` state to `undefined`, which you will then get that error when you try `props.recipes.map...`

Comment: It was previously returning data. But after some time i dont know why. Now in the console it is telling me "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" where i start mapping the elements

Comment: I think it was because I have went over the limit of api usage

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew notes in the comments, it sounds like the response from the server is `undefined`, and that's what is getting added to the recipes state object. You can check for this in the console. Are your API key and recipe name valid, for example? Are you accessing the correct part of the returned data?

As an aside, `recipes` in `state` is empty on the first render. You need to check for that possibility in your code. Here I've simply returned an empty div, but you could add a loading spinner or something there instead to provide useful feedback to the user.

```
render() {

  const { recipes } = this.state;

  if (!recipes.length) return <div />;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        React Cookbook
      </header>
      <InputForm getRecipe={this.getRecipe} />
      <Recipes recipes={recipes} />
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: would an empty recipes array return error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` ? I think that it would be fine. Like `[].map....`

Comment: No, but the `recipe` argument in the `map` callback with an empty `recipes` array certainly is.

Comment: if the array is empty I don't think the callback even gets executed.